# Converting Eurorack's -5/5 V to Raspberry Pi's 0/3.3 V

Tags: voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi, gpio

I would like to convert the voltages from my [Eurorack Modular Synthesizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_synthesizer) to the voltages accepted at the [GPIO](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/) pins of a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Computer and vice-versa.

Unfortunately I have no clue about electronics, yet i  know that the Eurorack-system works with voltages from **-5 to 5V** and the GPIO pins accept **0 to 3.3V**.

The Raspberry Pi runs on 5V DC (1A), in case this is or relevance.

I'd be gracious for any help.

Comment: Are these analogue voltages or digital levels?

Comment: in Eurorack, this may vary. Most of the time the levels are analog, though. GPIO is always digital to my knowledge.

Comment: So, please specify what you want - I saw you said GPIO and does this mean we can assume you mean digital voltages and not analogue voltages?

Comment: i thought this was made clear, i'm sorry. i would like read out the voltages sent from my Eurorack synthesizer at the GPIO pins of a Raspberry Pi Computer. The Voltage ranges differ, therefore i'm of the assumption that i need to convert them. i'm sorry for my latin – being at a very novice stage (and in this conversation, for this reason and for learning more), i'm not aware of the differences in analog and digital voltages and the like.

Comment: You can't read analogue voltages at a GPIO pin unless it has an alternative analogue function specified. Can you be clearer?

Comment: Analog vs Digital signals is the same as CV vs Gate signals in Eurorack. Analog signal has infinite number of values between min and max values. Digital signal has only two states: high and low. Which one do you need to receive on your Pi?

Comment: And BTW, Eurorack signals range between -10V to +10V. Not 5. In some cases they even reach ±12V.

Comment: that's a good start, thanks! i wasn't even aware of that :) i'm running an software i've written in Pure Data on a Raspberry Pi. In this software, i would like to be able to receive external voltages from a (music-)synthesizer. Eurorack synthesizers use (mostly analog) voltages in the range of -5/5V as control voltages for modulations and pitches – they "communicate" by means of this. If i found a way to read these (external) voltages into my software, i could use them to control aspects of this application.

Comment: @VolodymyrSmotesko thanks for this! wasn't aware... the standard to my knowledge is -5/5

Comment: @VolodymyrSmotesko basically i only need to receive pulses / gates. would this be simpler to achieve?

Comment: @benniy Yes, receiving just logic levels would be simple. See my answer. If you want to read analog values in the future, take a look at the ADC tutorial for Pi https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/overview

Answer (score 3):

First, there's no [ADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) on the Raspberry Pi, so you can't just read analog values with Pi even if you scale the voltage range to acceptable limits. All GPIO terminals on the Pi are digital.

If you just want to receive digital signals it's super easy to do with just a transistor. Here on this schematic the R2 and Q1 form a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider). The center point of the divider is connected to GPIO of Pi. 
When your input voltage is somewhere above 0 (so enough current is flowing into the base of Q1) the transistor will open so voltage between collector and emitter will become low. GPIO level would be low (0).
When input voltage is low or negative the transistor will close and it's resistance will be much higher than R1 so GPIO level will be high (1).
Effectively it is an inverting input, I think it shouldn't be a problem for your software.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSI5sM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You would have to connect 3 wires to your Pi GPIO header: +3.3V, GND, and one IO pin (input). 
And don't forget that input is two wires: the input signal and the ground connection.

The Q1 part number 2N3904 is just an example. Any small signal NPN transistor will work here.

Comment: thats simply incredible! perfectly explained for me to undertand – thanks a ton!!

Comment: can i use "any" 2N3904? finding lots of ones with this name and some letters behind :) like this one: https://www.conrad.de/de/transistor-bjt-diskret-fairchild-semiconductor-2n3904bu-to-92-3-1-npn-163350.html

Comment: @benniy yes, the letters after 3904 describe some technical details, most likely packaging. This transistor will work.

Comment: <3 t h a n k y o u !

Comment: hei @Volodymyr, i'm back :) have tried around and – it's weird... the first time i forgot the 100k resistor (amn't i stupid?) and it worked. then i recreated the circuit twice and it stopped working. i'll redo it tomorrow, but is there a) any change the 100k resistor is wrong or b) did i do a mistake when duplicating the circuit? here's a picture: https://picload.org/image/rpdpwccl/screenshot2017-06-30at23.44.20.png

Comment: Hey @benniy. You can damage the transistor without the resistor. But if it doesn't trigger with 100k you can try to replace it with 10k, so the transistor will get a little more base current.

Comment: thank you so much! running off to the supply store now :) (– but be warned, i might return here in a few hours. hehe)

Comment: super sorry – back already... before i go shopping – as i'll want to replicate this circuit multiple (~10) times: is there possibly a more efficient way to this? maybe one IC that has 10 2n3094 inside? or other parts as such? i just know so little, sorry to bug you and thanks !

Comment: @benniy such IC may exist. It would be called "transistor array". But 10 transistors cost just 2€ and will fit onto the smallest prototype PCB (you can even solder them directly onto jack connectors without the PCB), so it's not worth spending time to find such IC.

Comment: thanks @vlodymyr.. i'm back from the shop and will start building now. one really quick last question before i jump into it – would it be difficult adding an LED in the circuit to indicate if in input is high or low?

Comment: @benniy You can add a LED to output of this circuit. But this circuit can't output enough current for LED to light up, so you will have to amplify it with another transistor. Here's the simulated circuit http://tinyurl.com/y7dklshl Note that R3 there must be of high value because it lowers the output voltage. You don't want output to be too low. The LED will be inverted just as output: when input is low LED will be ON. R4 can be replaced with 560 Ohm for more brightness.

Comment: hei @volodymyr – just wanted to let you know: it worked! i skipped the LEDs but i'm the happiest person on earth right now :) thanks a ton for all your help!