# How to convert a +/-12 V digital signal to 0/+5 V?

Tags: level-shifting, logic-level

What would be a simple way to convert RS-232 +/-12 V digital levels into +5/0 V respectively?

1. I considered an optocouple, but I can't find one that can withstand -12 V reverse voltage. I considered adding a two-resistor voltage divider, but I suspect that will worsen the slew rate of the device, and I have no idea if that will be enough to become a problem (I'm aiming at the switching speed of 19 200 baud).
2. There's [this simple answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/313850/converting-euroracks-5-5-v-to-raspberry-pis-0-3-3-v), but it requires a transistor that can withstand +/-12 V as well - I'm looking for one right now but haven't found a suitable part yet. I'm also slightly worried about not having galvanic decoupling.
3. I considered a 5 V linear stabilizer, but I suspect it may not be fast enough to turn off/on, after all, they weren't designed for this task.

Perhaps, an optocouple with a bulky diode in series capable of withstanding -12 V?

Comment: EIA RS232 accepts both levels. Why convert?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75, I have not seen that mentioned anywhere yet. Can this be expected of a personal computer's COM port?

Comment: Yes because the Rx accepts any level in this range even down to +/-3V

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75: fair point, thank you, very useful info indeed!

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75: But wait, where am I going to get -3 V out of a +5 V device?

Comment: Rs232 V+ = TTL “0” and V- = Logic “1” for UART. The duplex IC Max232 generates V- using cap charge clamp pumps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not a MAX232? Purpose designed for exactly this application.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAX232

Comment: Hm, it didn't occur to me. Requires quite a few capacitors, but otherwise seems very simple to use and the price is low enough.

Comment: Also any other 5V powered RS232 receiver (or tranceiver) will do, and compatible clones of MAX232 tend to be cheaper. MAX232A and clones work with smaller capacitors than non-A version if it matters.